# bash: how do I parse the results of one command to use as match for another command

Tags: bash, grep

The intention of my script is to look for the usb printer and make sure the properties file is populated according to what's connected.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
ls -l /dev/usb | grep 'lp'
```

returns something like:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root lp   180, 1 Aug  5 11:32 lp1
crw-rw---- 1 root lp   180, 2 Aug  5 11:32 lp2
```

which I'd like to take the lp1 and lp2 values, and check my pos.properties file:

```
machine.printer=epson\:file,/dev/usb/lp2
machine.printer.3=epson\:file,/dev/usb/lp4
machine.printer.2=epson\:file,/dev/usb/lp1
```

for the strings '/dev/usb/lp1', '/dev/usb/lp2'. If both match, output 'OK, otherwise, output missing printer(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ok=1
for printer in /dev/usb/lp*; do
    if ! grep -wq "$printer" pos.properties; then
        ok=0
        echo "Missing $printer"
        break
    fi
done
(( ok )) && echo "OK"
```

Depending on the format of `pos.properties`, you may need a more specific command, for example,

```
if ! grep -wq "$printer" <(cut -d, -f2 pos.properties); then
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
cd /dev/usb/
arr=(lp*)

[[ $(grep -cFf <(printf "/dev/usb/%s\n" "${arr[@]}") pos.properties) -eq ${#arr[@]} ]] && 
    echo "OK" || echo "missing printer(s)"
```